# Python .py files with additional non-default imports - to binary on OSX

Tags: python, macos, cython, pyinstaller, py2app

I am quite new to python and I am looking for quite an easy feature - build binary out of python file.

This binary will be started on OSX, so no need to add python to this binary.

I decided to use Cython, and everything worked great for single py files.

However, I got two main problems with Cython.

- If I have multiple .py files, I don’t know how to add them to single binary (I use Cython with `--embed` option)
- I don’t know how to add imports that are not installed by default to the binary

Am I using the correct tool or it is better to use Py2App or PyInstaller for this?

Comment: As far as I know Py2App is intended for what you're asking.

Comment: Is it possible to create single binary (not the whole app) using Py2App?

Comment: You cannot create a single binary with py2app, it always creates an application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You might have more success with [Nuikta](http://nuitka.net), which is a tool that compiles python code into binaries and has an option for creating standalone binaries.

Comment: I have tried pyinstaller - it can create single binary as well!